# Getting the data of a dial pad while on a call

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I am creating a application where a user will get a call from a number and a .mp3 file start playing and the user can click any number from dial pad based on that number I have to perform action.

For this I have created a BroadcastReceiver which will check the phone state and at TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: I am playing mp3 clip.

Now I donot know how to react to dial paid key pressed.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import static android.content.Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PhoneStateChangeListener pscl = new PhoneStateChangeListener(context);
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(pscl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
class PhoneStateChangeListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    Context context;
    boolean isCalling=false;
    MediaPlayer mp=null;
    PhoneStateChangeListener(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state,incomingNumber);
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.abc);
        switch(state){
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                isCalling=true;
                mp.start();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can react to dial pad key pressed as:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
         // Do Code here
    }
else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0) {

   }
else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1) {

   }
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);}
```

From [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) you can get the more information about keys like 1 is pressed or 2 etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering can you please tell where I have to write this code